# Как сделать нумерованный список(ol) в explorer 7?

Tags: html, explorer

Есть задача сделать нумерованный список в 7 эксплорер во всех браузерах он отображается ну, а в "любимом" браузере нет.

Comment: если используется counter-reset - у него поддержка только по ie8 включительно

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol style="margin-left:25px;"> 
 <li>test1</li> 
 <li>test2</li> 
</ol>
```

У тебя походу есть css reset. Там margin = 0; попробуй добавить отступ!

Answer (score 0):

минимальный пример без стилей в IE7 работает:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1
            <li>Item 2
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

у вас скорее всего выставле нулевой margin:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>ol { margin: 0; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1
            <li>Item 2
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

<sub>[этот же вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401705/ordered-list-does-not-work-on-ie7-olli)</sub>

Comment: Не сильно это помогло психанул сделал через php